# print line space from a list in python

Tags: python, list, rows, whitespace

I would like to add user input in a list that contains rows, capitalize it and print it out again.

the result i receive:

```
Enter text rows to the message. Quit by entering an empty row.

Puff, the magic dragon lived by the sea, 

And frolicked in the autumn mist, in a land called Honah Lee.

The same, shouting: 

PUFF, THE MAGIC DRAGON LIVED BY THE SEA,
```

the next row line "and frolicked in ..." does not get printed.
my code is:

```
def main():

    print("Enter text rows to the message. Quit by entering an empty row.")
    entry = input()

    if entry == "":
        return

    else:
        print()
        msg = [entry]
        print("The same, shouting: ")
        print(''.join(msg).upper())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: You're only reading one line of input.

Comment: so how may i fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

`input()` only reads one line of input. If you want to get multiple lines, read them in a loop and append to a list.

```
def main():
    print("Enter text rows to the message. Quit by entering an empty row.")
    msg = []
    while True:
        entry = input()
        if entry == "":
            break
        msg.append(entry)

    if len(msg) == 0:
        return

    print()
    print("The same, shouting: ")
    print('\n'.join(msg).upper())
```